# RNGCryptoServiceProvider and Zeros?

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-4.0, random, rngcryptoserviceprovider

walking through some cryptogtaphy stuff , I saw that `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` has 2 methods :

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bs7131y.aspx)

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetNonZeroBytes
```

and

```
RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes
```

And so I ask :

What is *odd*  with  Filling  an array of bytes with a cryptographically strong sequence of random value which *some (0 or more)* of them are zeros ?
*(it is random values and apparently there wont be many zeros , and still zero is also a regular number)*

why did they created the distinguishing ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Within the .NET framework, [GetNonZeroBytes(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getnonzerobytes.aspx) is used when generating PKCS#1 padding for RSA encryption, which uses `0x00` as a seperator.

Using a tool like Reflector, you can see it used in [RSAPKCS1KeyExchangeFormatter.CreateKeyExchange(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58tf26wb) to implement padding as per [RFC 2313](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2313), section 8.1.2 ([RFC 3218](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3218#section-2) has some nice ASCII art that demonstrates the byte layout more clearly).

[GetNonZeroBytes(byte[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider.getnonzerobytes.aspx) could also be used to generate salt. The Cryptography StackExchange site has [a similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3396/why-x00-is-usually-avoided-in-salt) which suggests that avoiding `0x00` is to help with libraries and APIs that may treat the salt as a zero-terminated string, which would accidentally truncate the salt. However, unless one is using [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), this is unlikely to be a concern in .NET.

Comment: salt is just adding difficulty to rainbow table. it can be done with GetBytes  also  ....right ?

Comment: Correct, so long as you're sure that none of the places that use or store the salt have a problem with `0x00`. If unsure, you could always test it first with some salt that specifically contains `0x00` bytes.